# How to sort subscripts of symbols in an expression?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, subscript

For example, I want to change expr1 into expr2. I am pretty sure I can do this using nested loops to find and then modify terms with subscripts, but that is clunky, old school thinking. Is there a better way? "e" in my example below is a symbol (undefined).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(2 + Subscript[e, 2, 1] - Subscript[e, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]) /. 
     Subscript[z1_, z2__] :> Subscript[z1, Sequence @@ Sort[List[z2]]]

(* 2 + Subscript[e, 1, 2] - Subscript[e, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] *)
```

is one option.

Comment: This  is exactly the kind of solution I am looking for. Thank you so much. Now I'll try to digest how it works. I expect it will take me longer to digest it  than it took you to produce it.

Comment: I pretty much understand what you did and it is a very logical approach. I don't understand why a delayed rule rather than just a rule is needed, although I see that just a rule doesn't work at all. Is it difficult for you to explain what the delay does?

Comment: @matrixbud  Consider these simple cases.  `Subscript[e, 2, 1] /. Subscript[_, z2__] -> List[z2]` gives `{2, 1}` for `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`, as it should.  However, `Subscript[e, 2, 1] /. Subscript[_, z2__] -> Sort[List[z2]]` does not `Sort`, although `RuldDelayed` does.  This is because the normal rule does the `Sort` on `List[z2]` before `z2` is replaced by `2, 1`.  But, `RuleDelayed` does not do the `Sort` until after  `z2` is replaced by `2, 1`.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. To confirm that I understand how this works, I surmise that "List" is also delayed until after z2 is replaced, although that has no effect one way or the other on the final answer. That is, a delayed rule makes the direct substitution occur first and then all the subsequent operations (List and then Sort) happen after that.

Comment: @matrixbud  That is correct.  `f[2, 1] /. f[z__] -> {z}` and `f[2, 1] /. f[z__] :> {z}` both give `{{2, 1}`, because delaying evaluation makes no difference.  However, `f[2, 1] /. f[z__] -> Sort[{z}]` tries to `Sort` too soon and gives `{2, 1}`, while `f[2, 1] /. f[z__] :> Sort[{z}]` gives `{1, 2}`.